# How to hide element in *ngFor when specific value has been iterated over

Tags: angular, angular2-template

What is the proper way in Angular to not show an element in a `*ngFor` when a specific value has been iterated over? I tried it with putting it a new array and compare it but, it's complicated when the ngFor loops again all of the sudden.

**// method**

```ts
checkDateHeader(date) {
   if (this.dateHeaders.indexOf(date) > -1) {
       return false;
   } else {
       this.dateHeaders.push(date);
       console.log(this.dateHeaders);
       return true;
   }
}
```

**//template**

```html
<section *ngFor="let key of todoBacklog | OrderByDate;">
   <ion-list-header *ngIf="checkDateHeader(key.putInbacklogDate | date:'yMMMMEEEEd')">
      {{key.putInbacklogDate | date:'yMMMMEEEEd'}}
   </ion-list-header>
   <ion-card>
       <ion-item>
           <button ion-button icon-left clear item-right>
             <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
           </button>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-card-content>
           <ion-card-title>
              {{key.title}}
           </ion-card-title>
       </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a new property `seen` to items in todoBacklog, which is initialized to false.

Each time checkDateHeader is called, it sets it to true for that item. Then you can have a `<div *ngIf='key.seen>'`, which won't be enabled for the seen items.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question for the people who having the same problem. I had to empty the array dateHeaders when the angular detection cycle started (ngDoCheck). And added a seen property to the todoBacklog. Now it works on any changes (deletion, adding, moving) on the *ngFor loop object (todoBacklog).

```
// template    
<section *ngFor="let key of todoBacklog | OrderByDate; let i = index">
        <ion-list-header *ngIf=" !key.seen " text-left>
            {{ key.putInbacklogDate }}
        </ion-list-header>
</section>

// component.ts (important code)
@Component({
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
   selector: 'page-backlog',
   templateUrl: 'backlog.html',
})
export class Backlog {
    public todoBacklog: any = [];
    public dateHeaders: any = [];

    ngDoCheck() {
        this.dateHeaders = [];
        this.loopDateHeaders();
    }

    loopDateHeaders(){
        for (let key in this.todoBacklog){
            this.setDateHeader(key);
        }
    }

    setDateHeader( i) {
        if (this.dateHeaders.indexOf( this.todoBacklog[i].putInbacklogDate) > -1) {
            this.todoBacklog[i].seen = true;
        } else {
            this.dateHeaders.push(this.todoBacklog[i].putInbacklogDate);
            this.todoBacklog[i].seen   = false;
        }
    }
}
```